# How to load asp.net grid view code behind along with the grid view when page loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the grid view with Boundfield columns and am trying to replace Boundfield header text in code behind when the page loads. As per business, HeaderText has to change but in my case, the text is not changing immediately.

```
<asp:GridView ID="sampleGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="sampleGrid_RowDataBound" OnSorting="sampleGrid_Sorting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name"  SortExpression="Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void sampleGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row != null)
    {
        sampleGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "text";
    }
}
```

I added main logic of my code. Please let me know if there is any solution for my issue.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Value of the Header row on a Cell level in the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void sampleGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "text";
    }
}
```

Update

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
    lb.Text = "text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I added as you mentioned in cell level but Rows just lost click functionality. Previously I have the Click functionality for my row, where I am able to sort in Asc and desc

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience !! I updated code and added sorting expression.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But I am saying i am unable to click the row after adding text in cell level and In my case, I am sorting the columns after the click.

Comment: The sortable header is a LinkButton. So just look for that and change it's text. See update.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below

```
protected void sampleGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        LinkButton headerText = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton; 
        headerText.Text = "Michel";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply